# Neo4J OGM - org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException : Unknown Function ID()

Tags: java, swing, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I got

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; 
    Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Unknown Function ID()
```

when I use `session.save()` method in **Java Swing Application** in button listener method.

If I use same method and objects on **Console Application**, I've got **no exception**.

Neo4j version is "Neo4j 3.1 with OGM 2.2.1 version."

```
@NodeEntity
public class TestEntity {

@GraphId
private Long id;

private String name;

public TestEntity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I call below static method in button listener:

```
...
static save(){
TestEntity te = new TestEntity();
te.setName("AA");
session.save(te);
}...
```

Comment: Can you post the generated cypher query when calling `save` ? You should see it from the logs (DEBUG level).

Comment: I found the solution. The reason of the problem was using the locale language properties (Turkish). I've changed to English Locale it resolved. I don't know how can I use Neo4J - OGM with Turkish Locale. I need it. I hope they provide when we buy Neo4J.
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: The problem is solved with using Bolt driver configuration instead of embedded driver. I did not try with Http driver yet.